# how to set the path of local module in python to be recognized in CircleCI?

Tags: python, circleci

I am building a python module. In order to define its path, a `.pth` file has been defined as follows:

```sh
# creation of the virtual environment
python -v venv env

# activation of the newly creation virtual environment
source env/bin/activate
```

To set the path of my module (*my module is located in* `packages/regression_model/regression_model`) I created this `.pth` file  `env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/regression_model.pth` which contains:

```
# env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/regression_model.pth
../../../../packages/regression_model
```

Now, any where in my project, I can import my module `regression_model` through this command:

```py
import regression_model
```

Actually my objective is to use **CircleCI** for the deployment of my project.

**CircleCI** is configured as follows:

```
version: 2
jobs:
  test_regression_model:
    working_directory: ~/project
    docker:
      - image: circleci/python:3.7.6
        environment: # environment variables for primary container
          PYTHONPATH: ~/project/packages/regression_model:~/project/packages/ml_api
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Runnning tests
          command: |
            virtualenv venv
            . venv/bin/activate
            pip install --upgrade pip
            pip install -r packages/regression_model/requirements.txt
            chmod +x ./scripts/fetch_kaggle_dataset.sh
            ./scripts/fetch_kaggle_dataset.sh
            python packages/regression_model/regression_model/train_pipeline.py
            py.test -vv packages/regression_model/tests

workflows:
  version: 2
  test-all:
    jobs:
      - test_regression_model
```

**The problem** I am facing is that CircleCI is indicating that my module can not be imported

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "packages/regression_model/regression_model/train_pipeline.py", line 4, in <module>
    from regression_model import pipeline
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'regression_model'
```

To solve the problem, the path to that module `regression_model` has to be defined exactly as it was done locally. The question is then: how to define path in the CircleCI?

I tried to do it through the use of the environment variable `PYTHONPATH` but without success.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution. Similarly to what it has been done manually on my local machine, I just define 2 command lines to get it done in CircleCI:

```sh
echo "../../../../packages/regression_model" >> env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/extra.pth
echo "../../../../packages/ml_api" >> env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/extra.pth
```

And below the full yml file just in case it could help others.

```
version: 2
jobs:
  test_regression_model:
    working_directory: ~/project
    docker:
      - image: circleci/python:3.7.6
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Runnning tests
          command: |
            virtualenv env
            . env/bin/activate
            pip install --upgrade pip
            pip install -r packages/regression_model/requirements.txt
            echo "../../../../packages/regression_model" >> env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/extra.pth
            echo "../../../../packages/ml_api" >> env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/extra.pth
            chmod +x ./scripts/fetch_kaggle_dataset.sh
            ./scripts/fetch_kaggle_dataset.sh
            sudo apt-get install unzip
            unzip  packages/regression_model/regression_model/datasets/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques.zip -d packages/regression_model/regression_model/datasets/
            python packages/regression_model/regression_model/train_pipeline.py
            py.test -vv packages/regression_model/tests

workflows:
  version: 2
  test-all:
    jobs:
      - test_regression_model
```